# Is it possible to extarct path parameter and url in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am actually trying to separate `URL` and path parameters in jersey implementation.

My request URL is `/web/seller/{pathpartma1}/{pathparam2}`

I need to get the following data from the request

```
Request url: /web/seller
Parameter1 name = pathpartma1
Parameter2 name = pathparam2
```

My method looks like this

```
@GET
@Path(value = "/web/seller/{pathparam1}/{pathparam2}")
@Produces(MediaType.JSON)
public String myMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@PathParam("pathparam1") String pathparam1, @PathParam("pathparam2") String pathparam2)
{
    /////
 }
```

Can some one tell if it is possible to extract url and path parameter names in my method.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: @kocko. Apologies, I have updated the question. Can you check.

Comment: what's happening? is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your Path is incorrect - the lef tbrace is missing at the end.

Comment: This is the right answer. However, when you see simple issues like this, it is recommended to vote to close the question as "cannot reproduce / simple typo". This should help SO keep the number of questions that are useless to future visitors to a minimum.